# <br> stored in mysql field but no line break when echo

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am storing data in a field named `message`. An example of this field is:

```
<br /><br />

shane!

<br /><br />

****** Original Message ******

Test Back


<br /><br />


****** Original Message ******

test
```

When I `echo` this into a `<textarea>` field, it is displayed as this:

```
shane! ****** Original Message ****** Test Back ****** 
Original Message ****** test
```

How do I `echo` this to include the line breaks?

Comment: You need to look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: Are you using any framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When outputting to a textarea you must call <del>`htmlentities`</del> `htmlspecialchars` if your text contains HTML.

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text); ?></textarea>
```

That will convert your `<br />` to `&lt;br /&gt;`. If you leave the `<br />` unencoded they will simply be interpreted as HTML.

If your goal is to display `<br />` or other HTML in the textarea as it is written in the database you must escape all code that would otherwise be interpreted as HTML.

**edit**

If you want to output line breaks instead of `<br />` you can use `str_replace`:

```
<textarea><?php echo str_replace('<br />', "\r\n", $textarea); ?></textarea>
```

But remember that all other HTML will be interpreted and not displayed. I think you should solve your problem at the source and store the CRLF in the database if you don't need the HTML.

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: The goal isn't to display `<br />` in the textarea, it's to actually show line breaks.

Comment: @Charlie that wasn't so clear to me. @user2149630 do you need to output the text as it is in the databease or do you need to replace `<br />` with a line break?

Comment: @Sébastien He wrote "How do I echo this to include the line breaks?"

Answer (score 2):

You can try `str_replace` to replace the `<br />` tags into end of line characters.

```
 str_replace('<br />', PHP_EOL, $textarea);
```

Comment: so do i need to save the <br> as /n istead?

Comment: does `str_replace('<br />', PHP_EOL, $textarea);` go before my texarea?

Comment: Just replacing `<br />` with `\n` won't give you an actual line break.

Comment: @user2149630 Hi method works to replace all `<br />` instances with newline characters, `\n`, therefore showing line breaks in the `text area`. Assign the `str_replace()` to a variable, like `$new = str_replace(...)`, then `echo $new` in the `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

The  tag does not accept HTML code inside of it. Instead, you need to format your code as in a plain text file. Check this example:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea

Now replace the source code with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website.



We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

You will see that formatting inside of the textarea works pretty much like the  tag. So the answer to your question is that you need to replace each 
 by a newline character.