# Should I store the textarea's new lines as <br> in MySQL databes or not?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am clueless what is the good way.

If I have the content of a textarea like this:

```
Hi,

I would like to offer you these things:

1) Car
2) Book
3) Airplane

And some other things as well.

Sincerely,
Tim
```

Should I save the content as it is (after sanitizing malicious code etc.) and then use nl2br() when outputing into html view?

Or I should use nl2br() before saving into db and then just call it in the view as it is saved in the db, in this case:

```
Hi,<br>
<br>
I would like to offer you these things:<br>
<br>
1) Car<br>
2) Book<br>
3) Airplane<br>
<br>
And some other things as well.<br>
<br>
Sincerely,<br>
Tim<br>
```

I would like to know what approach is the best from the db point of view (less space taken, faster, etc.) and what is more universal (using it later for emails, parsing, etc.)

If I look at it from my point of view, it's better to use 1 nl2br() function when saving instead of many nl2br() functions during the rendering in my html view.

What is your take on this "dilemma"?

Comment: I would use `\n` instead.

Comment: What function in PHP do you use for this? Btw. I am using Laravel as well, if that helps. What about parsing and HTML/PHP support? \n is ambiguous <br> is very specific. Html view doesn't accept \n but it accepts <br>. I save a lot on calling functions if I use <br>, but maybe that's the wrong appraoch. But that's my take. It's sad that only you have written a comment and no other people commented so far ;(

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918287/br-stored-in-mysql-field-but-no-line-break-when-echo

Comment: @PHPLover I know how to echo text with linebreaks in textareas etc. That's not a problem. I am looking into a deeper pragmatic approach. A longterm solution. Right now, I am in favor of storing the stuff as it is or with line breakes (<br>). Storing it with linebreakes is more effieicent in my opinioin, I use a special function nl2br only once - before saving. I have about 100 items per page and that's 100x nl2br() instead of 0x if I save it with <br>. But I am waiting for some other opinions as well.

Comment: I see what you mean about only calling nl2br once when saving, but for a long term solution you may want to consider how else the data could be used - could it be output in another format, such as text, or PDF, or within XML or something? If that possibility does (or even might in future) exist, then IMHO I'd save it with something generic like `\n`, and then, at the point of output, format the text appropriately to the medium you are outputting to. It takes up slightly more processing power and slightly more code, but it's probably easier to maintain overall.